# onStart() not being called

Tags: android

My app has one primary activity which houses 5 fragments. Everything is working fine except if I were to close the app and restart it, then the app opens with a blank screen (i.e. no fragment loaded) instead of the assigned default fragment. So I tried to override onStart() but now it is crashing with the following error:

```
08-04 10:59:42.748 27413-27413/com.paraway.partner E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.paraway.partner, PID: 27413
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1536)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1558)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:317)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:282)
        at com.eataway.partner.MainActivity.openOrders(MainActivity.java:42)
        at com.eataway.partner.MainActivity.onStart(MainActivity.java:93)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1265)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6915)
        at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:6974)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSleeping(ActivityThread.java:4864)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3600(ActivityThread.java:221)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2031)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

**MainActivity.class** looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(navigationItemSelectedListener);

        openOrders();
    }

    // Open default/main fragment
    private void openOrders() {
        bundle.putString("userId", getUser());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new OrdersFragment()).commit();
    }

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationItemSelectedListener = menuItem -> {
        // Handling bottom navigation
        return true;
    };

    private String getUser() {
        // non relevant code needed in the fragments
        return userId;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        openOrders();
        super.onStart();
    }
}
```

I just want to be able to open the default fragment if the app were to be resumed or restarted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you see the blank screen is because you are starting a fragment transaction in `onCreate()` of your activity, this get's called only one time depending on the lifecycle of the app. If your activity is stopped in `onCreate()`, it will follow a pattern, `onCreate()` -> `onPause()` -> `onStop()` -> `onSaveInstance()`.

What you need to do is to override `onPostResume()` and start your fragment transaction there. This callback will be invoked when the activity is fully settled and is visible. Also, `commit()` does not mean it will commit the transaction immediately, instead it is scheduled, which explains why this exception is thrown because the commit happens when the activity is no longer available.

Post Honeycomb, activities are considered killable after `onStop()`

```
 @Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();

   if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container) == null)
        openOrders();
}
```

Comment: Hi Taseer, I understand what you mean and tried a variety of different things  (adding a fragment instead of replacing, tried another fragment altogether) with no success. Of course, I tried exactly what you posted as well but I still get an empty container.

Comment: Were you getting empty container before? What's the purpose of this code `bundle.putString("userId", getUser());` ?

Comment: Yes, I was always getting an empty container.

Comment: The purpose of that is to get the userId that I pass in a bundle to the fragment. The fragment then retrieves the Id, and uses it to query the backend and populates the recyclerview which is what I want to maintain when the app is closed in the background.

Comment: In that case, I don't see that you are passing that bundle to the fragment. Also, put `Log.d("Fragment, "onCreate)` in your fragment's `onCreate()`. Also, remove `openOrders()` from your actvity's `onStart()`.

Comment: Got it. Yes that was the issue + what your stated in the original answer. Thanks.